# Error handling for excel addin that cannot find networking drive

Tags: excel, vba, add-in, office-addins, excel-addins

I have made an addin and placed it on a shared networking drive.

The addin contains a seperat sub that calls the addin whenever an excel document is opened, so the addin will be available in excel all the time.

The addin works fine when i am in my office and when i am connected, however if i for example work from home, and opens excel, then excel gives me the following error:
"Sorry we couldn't find . Is it possible it was moved, renamed or deleted?"
This is because i am not connected and excel cannot retrieve the path i am trying to call the addin from.

Is there a way to handle this error, so the message dont show up? I have tried to ignore the error so the message dont show up but that does not work. How can i exit the sub before the error appears? or an even better solution is to call custom made addins without using a specific networking drive as location.

I have tried the following code to ignore the error.

````
Sub Open_up () 

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

On Error Resume Next 

Call 'name of the addin 

End Sub ```

Hope it makes sense
````

Comment: Before you call the Addin, check that the path is valid first e.g. `If Dir([path]) <> "" Then [Call addin etc] Else [do something else if path not valid]`

Comment: Hey Raymond, thanks for the suggestion. I tried the below but i still get the error when i am not connected,                                                                                                        
`Dim path As String

path = "V:\Add_Ins\Addins.xlam"

If Dir([path]) <> "" Then

Call CreateMenuMaker

Else

Exit Sub

End If`

Comment: By error, do you mean the same error ("Sorry we couldn't find . Is it possible it was moved, renamed or deleted?")? `Dir([path])` should be `Dir(path)`

Comment: I changed to `Dir(path)` and the same error still occurs. Yes it is still "Sorry we couldn't find . Is it possible it was moved, renamed or deleted?"

Comment: I guess it is because i have added the add-in, in excel under options->Add-in->Manage Excel add-in->Go and then a check mark at the specific add-in. So whenever i am disconnected then it cant find the addin and that has nothing to do with the sub calling it. It is the location of the path of the disconnected networking drive

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the add-in was not loaded and not accessible from the shared drive. I'd suggest creating an installer for the add-in, so it could be installed on the end user machines. See [Deploy an Office solution by using Windows Installer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/deploying-an-office-solution-by-using-windows-installer?view=vs-2022) for more information.